# enviar datos desde controlador con condiciones al .blade con laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Bien, tengo 2 tablas;
`PROFORMA` - `EQUIPOS` (una tercera que es proyecto, pero esa relación no es el probema)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien en la programación lo que necesito hacer es algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Lo que tenia que hacer ya esta solucionado, el asunto es que quisiera que esto se haga en el controlador y no en el blade.

Bien ahora el asunto es que, tengo hecha una condicion en `proformas.blade` donde verifica que el `fk_equipos_proforma` sea igual al `id` de la proforma para que cuando haga el `@foreach` me muestre los equipos correspondientes a esa proforma, por que son `n` proformas que se muestran no 1.

y quiero ver si alguien me puede ayudar con la condicion que tengo el el blade lo lo puedo hacer en el controlador:

Condicion blade:

```
    <tbody class="t-equipos-body">
      @foreach ($filas as $item2)
           <tr>
               @if ($item->id_proforma == $item2->fk_equipos_proforma)
                 <td>{{$item2->descripcion}}</td>
                 <td>{{$item2->cantidad}}</td>
                 <td>$ {{$item2->precio_unidad}}</td>
                 <td>$ {{$item2->total_fila}}</td>
              @endif  
           </tr>
       @endforeach                
    </tbody>
```

Entonces mi duda es como hacer en el controlador la consulta que me pueda hacer esa misma condición.

```
 @if ($item->id_proforma == $item2->fk_equipos_proforma)
```

> **`$item  (PROFORMA)`**
>   **`$item2 (EQUIPOS)`**

por ahora solo tengo estas consultas:

```
 $proformas = DB::table('proforma')->where('fk_proforma_proy', $datos)->get();

    $filas = DB::table('equipos')->where('fk_equipos_proy',$datos)->get();
```

Comment: @BetaM, en que parte hago eso que comentas "¿por qué a parte relacionas proforma y equipos?" para entender a lo que te refieres, no entendí tu pregunta.

Comment: @BetaM, la relación es de 1 a muchos, una proforma tiene muchos equipos. pero todos están relacionados a un mismo proyecto. a lo mejor en el gráfico no me di a entender es que en si son muchos datos que tiene cada tabla y quería hacerlo simple.

Comment: @BetaM, si esa es la idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tu escenario requerimos de 2 modelos, los cuales son:

- Proforma
- Equipo

La sintaxis es simple:

```
php artisan make:model NombreModelo
```

Cada uno de estos modelos, van a tener una relación declarada que los vincule con su modelo contraparte, de la siguiente forma:

El modelo Proforma tiene muchos equipos entonces usa el método `hasMany()` así:

```
class Proforma extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "proforma";
    public function equipos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Equipo::class, 'Fk_equipos_proforma');
    }
}
```

Por otro lado Equipo pertence a... y entonces usa el método `belongsTo()` así:

```
class Equipo extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "equipos";
    public function proforma()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Proforma::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora construimos la consulta donde:

- Invocamos al modelo Proforma
- Le hacemos una carga ambiciosa de sus relaciones con `eager loading` pasando como argumento el nombre de la relación
- Filtramos las proformas por medio de su `id` para solo obtener los equipos relacionados a ella

De esta forma:

```
$equiposProforma = Proforma::with('equipos')->findOrFail($idProforma);
```

Donde `$idProforma` es la variable que almacena el id de la proforma que deseas usar para obtener sus equipos relacionados.

Finalmente para poder iterarlos hacemos lo siguiente en la vista

```
@foreach($equiposProforma as $equipoProforma)
    {{ propiedadUnoProforma }}
    {{ propiedadDosProforma }}
    @foreach($equipoProforma->equipos as $equipo)
        {{ propiedadUnoEquipos }}
        {{ propiedadDosEquipos }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

La consulta anterior te debería estar devolviendo a nivel del primer foreach los valores de las propiedades del modelo proforma y dentro del segundo foreach los valores de las propiedades del modelo Equipo.

En cambio si deseas todas las proformas con sus equipos asociados entonces solo sustituye el uso de `findOrFail()` por el de `get()`, el resto debería quedar igual:

```
$equiposProforma = Proforma::with('equipos')->get();
```

Aclaraciones:

- Tus tablas al no seguir en sus nombres las convenciones de Laravel debes declarar en los modelos una propiedad igualada al nombre de cada una de ellas
- La llave foránea que vincula a equipos con proforma tampoco sigue la convención de nombres que Eloquent espera que sería: `columna_id` entonces en el método `hasMany()` como segundo argumento debes pasar como string el nombre de dicha llave foránea.

**Referencias**

- [Convenciones en Modelos](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)
- [Relación hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: no comprendo lo de $idProforma donde la declaro, primera vez que utilizo modelos, creo que ese es el único fallo que me genera hasta ahora.

Comment: @DuvalAD la variable `$idProforma` que coloqué es para indicar donde almacenarías el posible id de la proforma por la cual quieres firltrar, la cual no es estrictamente necesaria pues tu puedes pasar directamente el id de la proforma en formato de número

Comment: al parecer si seria la solución, al parecer pero no he usado modelos y me están generando errores. quizás sea por que se bien como funcionan, no he leído la documentación de eloquent, igual muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Si te presenta errores considera agregarlos y te oriento :)

Comment: el problema al parecer son los nombres de los modelos con las tablas, ese era uno.

Comment: Ok edito con esa aclaración

Comment: Espero la edición te ayude, de seguir presentando errores no dudes en comentarlos